# Is product of two VC subgraphs a VC subgraph?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, information-theory

Let $X$ be a set of points. 
**Def 1**: A subgraph of a real function on $X$ is the set
$$G_f:= \{ (t,x) : t\leq f(x) \quad t \in \mathbb{R} ,\quad x \in X\}$$
**Def 2** A class of functions $\mathcal{F}$ is a VC subgraph of index $v$ if the class of sets $C:= \{ G_f : f \in \mathcal{F}\}$  is a VC ( [Vapnik-Chervonenkis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension)) of dimension $v$.

**My question**:
If $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are VC subgraph on $X$, is $\mathcal{F} \mathcal{G}:= \{ fg : f\in \mathcal{F} , g \in \mathcal{G} \}$ is also a VC subgraph?

Comment: why does $f$ not appear on the RHS in the definition of $G_f$?

Comment: @LukeCollins you are right.Updated

Comment: I don't remember a counterexample off the top of my head, but I think this is not true even for sums, let alone products. However, you can derive entropy bounds for $\mathcal{FG}$ from those for $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$, and often this is enough. I'd guess something like van der Vaart & Wellner would have the counterexample. Lemma 7.19 [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~bodhi/Talks/Emp-Proc-Lecture-Notes.pdf) lists the entropy bound.

Comment: @stochasticboy321: Great remark! I think you understand what I'm facing, however in my problem, the class $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{G}$ is too big.